# php+mysql: copying a row from one table to another

Tags: php, mysql, optimization, query-optimization

I'm having two tables `table`(fieldA, fieldB, fieldC) and `log_table`(id, fieldA, fieldB, fieldC). Is it possible to copy a row from `table` to `log_table` with one (not two: select and insert) query?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: .:are you to copy a single record or a multiple record?

Comment: I need to copy a _single_ row

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a single **INSERT** statement passing a **SELECT** query instead of a list of constant values:

```
INSERT INTO log_table (SELECT fieldA, fieldB, fieldC FROM table)
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you want. But maybe something like this:

```
INSERT INTO log_table( fieldA, fieldB, fieldC)
SELECT fieldA, fieldB, fieldC FROM table
```